# Injecting into <head> in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a few EXTERNAL scripts that need to be loaded on various pages, such as Google Places Autocomplete, Facebook APIs, etc.

Obviously it does not make sense to load them on every route, however the documentation does not address this rather common scenario.

Furthermore, the Vue instance mounts onto a tag within the body, since

> the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance
>   to < html > or < body >.

How are real world applications currently dealing with this situation?

Comment: You should be using `require()` or `import` within your components. It allows you to dynamically load scripts per component. You need to make sure to `npm install` the dependencies.

Comment: Geez what the hell is up with the downvotes? How is this not a sensible question?

Comment: Something like [vue-headful](https://github.com/troxler/vue-headful)?

Comment: Have you looked at Vue-helmet. https://github.com/jnields/vue-helmet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't addressed in documentation because it's not Vue's job. Vue is meant for creating, among other things, single page applications (SPA). In a single page application you typically load all your vendor scripts (Google, Facebook, etc.) and your own scripts and styles the first time the site loads.

A lot of real world applications just bundle all their vendor scripts into a single file (example: vendor.js) using Webpack, Gulp, Grunt or some other bundling tool. The rationale is that you can pack all those scripts into a single file, minify them, serve them with gzip compression and then it's only a single request.

Smarter bundlers like Webpack and Browserify can walk the dependency tree if you're using `require()` or `import` to import your modules. This can be allow you to split your dependencies into several logical chunks so components and libraries only load load with their dependencies if they themselves are loaded.

Comment: What about external scripts? (and I think you meant SPA not SAP)

Comment: Fixed the typo. External scripts are also loaded when the site first loads.

Comment: So if you have N scripts that each individually go on N individual pages, you load them all on first load ?

Comment: Generally, yes. There isn't much of an alternative if they're external. Typically your page doesn't need them all loaded at once before it can start your application and they all load async so your application can be running while the facebook API loads in the background, for example.

Comment: If your app is large you should be using async components to separate concerns.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

Comment: -1 for "Vue is meant for creating single page applications (SPA)".  One of the points of Vue is it can be used as a component on existing legacy pages.  The answer is fine, but it's premise is flawed.

Comment: @NathanGoings that's a strange reason to down vote. Given the question, it's pretty clear they're building a SPA and wondering how to selectively load vendor modules. There is no issue with the premise, especially given the context, which is why the answer was accepted. I've added "among other things" as a clarification. Down votes are usually reserved for answers that poorly address the question, not ones that omit a full definition for the sake of brevity. Note also, the Vue.js tag on the question has an official definition already.

Comment: @Soviut, I came to this thread via a different search.  The question was confusing so I started reading answers, I realized things weren't as I expected.  This whole thread needs more clarity, but I'm not sure how to improve it.

Comment: @NathanGoings this isn't a forum and these aren't threads, so if you have a better answer, please add it so it can get upvotes.

Comment: What about for adding third-party code, like analytics software that requires information of the user logged in? There's need for it at that point.

Comment: @EricMcWinNEr most analytics libraries have ways of updating tracking markers like the current user ID after they're loaded. This is so that if is logged out, analytics can still be captured, and if they log in they gain the marker. Additionally, these libraries can also be disabled on the fly for GDPR without having to reload them.

Comment: What about for configuring the official npm module for the vue devtools? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/devtools This lets you use the devtools for browsers that don't have the extension installed e.g. safari or in cypress. The npm page for the devtools says to add a script tag. It would be nice to use vue to dynamically add this script tag depending on the environment i.e. not production

Comment: @aleph_one You shouldn't do that with Vue, you should use build tools to conditionally render the script tag based on environment. If you're building in production, the build tool automatically excludes it.

Comment: @Soviut Thanks for clarifying, you are correct. I will add for anyone looking to add the vue-devtools module to your project who would like simpler config. You can import the devtools as a module with `import devtools from '@vue/devtools'` and then connect them in your application code with `devtools.connect(/* host, port */)`, which lets you avoid the need for dynamic script tags

Answer (score 13):

I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head, it is exactly designed to inject the data you want from your component into the document's head.
Perfect for SEO title and meta tags.

To be used like so:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    title: 'My Title'
  }),

  head: {
    // creates a title tag in header.
    title () {
      return {
        inner: this.title
      }
    },
    meta: [
      // creates a meta description tag in header.
      { name: 'description', content: 'My description' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: FINALLY. I was searching forever for a similar package to react-helmet, but my google-fu wasn't helping, and the `vue-helmet` repo is horribly out of date (obvious first search result match)

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue as well. We load JavaScripts by other means. We created a library that does this for us (quick and dirty, observing browser events and adding the JavaScript tag). This library also, implements a mediator pattern (https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#mediatorpattern) fires an event of "page:load" (custom for us) at the very end once all libraries have been loaded.
Our VueJS components are executed only when that event fires. This also allowed us to put Vue components in the header tag instead of body, as the browser will load it, but not execute the function until the event is fired.

```
var loadVueComponents=function()
{
    var myComponents=new Vue({....});
};
Mediator.subscribe("page:load",loadVueComponents);
```

Before I get downvotes for not using Webpack or any of those other tools, this was an old application with a lot of JavaScripts (some cannot be minified or even concatenated/bundle with other files) and we needed to add some new components (now using Vue) and trying to disrupt as little as possible existing pages (mediator pattern was already implemented and loading dynamic libraries based on page attributes)

Comment: No reason to excuse for NOT using a framework

Comment: window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    loadVueComponents();
})

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about some external JS which are not part of node-modules and want to retrieve from external source (http://your-external-script) then you can go for dynamic loading of JS script tag. Put this code somewhere like you first landing screen of SPA in before transition event.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "htpps://your-external-script.js";
document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
```

This will make your external file available in global scope and then you can use it anywhere.

**Note**: this scenario is where you dont haev node-moduels for library or you dont want to put as load modules